# How can I programmatically set Visible for User Month in Infragistics.Win.UltraWinSchedule.UltraCalendarCombo?

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I use `UltraCalendarCombo` in my project. I want user to see some preselected date in dropdown datepicker. This preselected date is calculated based on some another properties.
I do the next thing:

```
var calendarInfo = ultraGridCalendar.CalendarInfo;
calendarInfo.ActivateDay(selectedDate);
```

But this code does not work as I expect. It just selects this day, but user should manually navigate to year and month, which corresponds to selected date. I want calendar combo to show selected date, i.e. month and year.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the desired behavior. Does your code behind select the DD portion of the date only, forcing users to pick MM YYYY? Or is the intent that it select MM/DD/YYYY by default?

Comment: `selectedDate` is preselected date (i. e. not only day). `calendarInfo.ActiveDay` is of type `Day`, which contains not only DD, it contains month and year also in his state.
The desired behavior is as follow:
assume that preselected date is `01-Mar-2010`, then when user clicks dropdown this date should be highlighted in either way and showed to user. User should see March of 2010 and highlighter 01 there. But this date should not appear as text in cell, it should be only highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer on my question.
There is `VisibleMonths` property in UltraCalendarCombo, but it is non-editable and it contains visible months. But there is another useful for me property: `FirstMonth`. This property is all I need in my case. It has setter, and I can change visible to user month, after activating day.
All code:

```
var calendarInfo = ultraGridCalendar.CalendarInfo;
calendarInfo.ActivateDay(selectedDate);
ultraGridCalendar.FirstMonth = calendarInfo.GetMonth(selectedDate);
```

I do this all in AfterDropDown event handler of the editor of the cell.
So, when user clicks on dropdown, he can see date, that I want him to see by default.

You can use setter of `ultraGridCalendar.Value` property, but then in text box you will see this value, and underlying model will contain this value. Desired behavior was not selecting value instead of user, just highlighting "suggestion".